# Getting Outlook data via python-o365

Tags: python-3.x, azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Well, I would like to get a calendars data from outlook. My purpose is making small service in Python which can read & write in someones calendar in outlook account of course I suppose that I was provided access to it in Azure Active Directory. Before writing this, I read a lot of guides on how to do this. Also I tried to find similar issues on [github](https://github.com/O365/python-o365/issues), some things I've learned from this.

So I've made following steps. I wish you pointed on my mistakes and told how to fix them.

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
- [image]
  Then I've written this code in Python with O365

```
from O365 import Account

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx'
SECRET_ID = 'xxxx'
TENANT_ID = 'xxxx'

credentials = (CLIENT_ID, SECRET_ID)
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id=TENANT_ID)
if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!')


schedule = account.schedule(resource='user@domain')
calendar = schedule.get_default_calendar()
events = calendar.get_events(include_recurring=False)

for event in events:
    print(event)
```

Then if I use email which is shown in user contact info in my directory as a resourse. I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain/calendar | Error Message: The tenant for tenant guid 'xxxx' does not exist.
```

Then if I use 'User Principal Name', which is shown in user identity in my directory as a resourse. I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxx#EXT%23@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendar | Error Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Then if I use 'me' as a resource I also get an error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar | Error Message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.
```

Could you tell me what should i provide as a resource to get someones calendar or maybe what should i fix?

Comment: Please check this it may help you : https://github.com/O365/python-o365#calendar

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT thank you for commenting. I guess I've found the solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For me, joining [Microsoft Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program) and using its azure directory fixed issues.

Answer (score 0):

let's best go through the error messages:

1. `Error Message: The tenant for tenant guid 'xxxx' does not exist.`

I am assuming that this is an Office 365 Business. Also that you are logged into Azure with your company address.
Then you should see under: "App registrations>test feature> Overview" you should find the valid TenantID.

[image: Tenant ID]

2. `Error Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

I cant find a Scope in your example e.g:

```
from O365 import Account

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx'
SECRET_ID = 'xxxx'
TENANT_ID = 'xxxx'

credentials = (CLIENT_ID, SECRET_ID)

scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendar.ReadWrite', 
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read', 
          'https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access']

account = Account(credentials, tenant_id=TENANT_ID)
if account.authenticate(scopes=scopes):
   print('Authenticated!')
```

you can [check all Scopes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

3 . `Error Message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.`

I also assume a scope error here.

General recommendations:

- Add "offline_access" as a scope - this way you don't need to log in for each run.
- Set each scope as delegated - this limits the rights on user level - which is a reduced security risk for a company.