# Creating a Calendar event O365 package in python?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I'm trying to make a script to add Calendar events to my main calendar in outlook using python and the O365 package. But I keep running into various issues with creating a sample event. any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT UPDATED CODE WITH NEW PROBLEM: Still getting a 401 error but now its saying my token is unauthorized/no permissions.

The error:

```
Authenticated!
Client Error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized 
for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemail@hotmail.com/calendar
Error Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood
```

code is below:

```
from O365 import Account, MSGraphProtocol
import win32com.client as client
from O365 import Protocol
import datetime as dt

protocol_graph = MSGraphProtocol()
scopes_graph = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
account = Account(credentials,auth_flow_type= 'credentials', tenant_id= My_Tenant_Id)

if account.authenticate(scopes=scopes_graph):
print('Authenticated!')

schedule = account.schedule(resource= 'myemail@hotmail.com')
calendar = schedule.get_default_calendar()
new_event = calendar.new_event()
new_event.subject = 'Recruit George!'
new_event.location = 'Courthouse'
new_event.start = dt.datetime(2022,4,20)
new_event.save()
```

api permissions:
[image]

UPDATE here is the auth token results from
Jwt.ms
image
[image]

Comment: The problem here is with scope. Please provide only `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as your scope and test it.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma I edited and updated the question. I changed the scope and schedule to link to my email account. But I'm still getting a 401 error but it now says no permission even though I've authenticated.

Comment: Have you added the Application permission(Calendar.ReadWrite) in the Azure AD?

Comment: Yes I have my app permissions here in the screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/92wbLqS)

Comment: The link which you shared is not opening for me. Can you paste the image in the question? Also check if you have provided admin consent to Calendars.ReadWrite.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma ok i updated the question with the photo sorry about that. I also have both selected for Calendars.ReadWrite. (delegated and admin consent) Trying to get something to work.

Comment: Please grab the access token and put it in https://jwt.ms and check if you have the correct permission or not.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma hello I uploaded photo of token results in jwt.ms

Comment: The main reason you are getting 401 is because thr URL - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemail@hotmail.com/calendar` has MSA account(`myemail@hotmail.com`)...you should try with Work account

Comment: [401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myemail@hotmail.com/calendar | Error Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/807243/401-client-error-unauthorized-for-url-httpsgraphmi.html)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @*Shiva Keshav Varma* & *CarlZhao-MSFT*,

---

> The error you are getting, *Because dynamic permissions are not
> supported by the client credential flow, you should remove /Calendars.
> ReadWrite. Shared. All application rights are already in the /.default
> scope.*

---

*To use the correct script you can try with following;*

```
 scopes_graph = ['basic','https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
```

please refer this link for similar discussion : [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/806878/creating-new-events-in-calendar-with-o365-api-pyth.html)

For more information please refer the below links:

- **SO THREAD**|[***Getting Outlook data via python-o365***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222086/getting-outlook-data-via-python-o365)
- [***GitHub Sample***](https://github.com/O365/python-o365)
- **BlogPost**|[***How To Read Microsoft Outlook Calendars with Python***](https://pietrowicz-eric.medium.com/how-to-read-microsoft-outlook-calendars-with-python-bdf257132318)